# List containing number and name sorting

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sorting, python-3.4

So this program stores a name and score, then stores it in a tet document, and sorts it into a top 5 leaderboard with score followed by name.
The file is written as score,name,score,name...
But when printing the final sorted list, it is sorting the scores as strings and not integers- eg. `98 97 87774 384 111 10000000`
and not `10000000 87774 384 111 98 97`

```
#importing os
import os
#checkingn if the file is empty
if os.stat("scores.txt").st_size == 0:
    #if it is, setting up 5 blank scores to correct the ',' start and to 
make the leaderboard more presentable
    f = open('scores.txt','w')
    f.write('0,Empty,0,Empty,0,Empty,0,Empty,0,Empty')
#input of new score and name
score = input('score: ')
name = input('Name: ')
#storing it
f = open('scores.txt','a+')
f.write(',')
f.write(score)
f.write(',')
f.write(name)
f.close()
#reading the file with , as a split so forming a list
f = open('scores.txt','r')
data = f.readline()
# Get and strip all data from the input string.
numdata = [value.strip() for value in data.split(',') if value is not '']
# Create pair from each name/score
data = list(zip(numdata[0::2], numdata[1::2]))
# Sort by score
leaderboard = sorted(data, key =lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print(leaderboard)
f.close()
```

If anyone knows how I can fix this it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the score to an integer with the `int()` constructor in your key function for the scores to be sorted numerically:

```
leaderboard = sorted(data, key =lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)
```

If you want only the top 5 then you should also slice the resulting list:

```
leaderboard = sorted(data, key =lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)[:5]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can Also apply the int cast this way:

```
data.sort(key=int, reverse=True)

dara[:5].sort(key=int, reverse=True) # for first five
```

Where data is an array of strings.

Notice that the sort is in place, so you don't create another list in memory.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the top 5 scores, there's no need to sort the entire list of scores. You can use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to track and output to the top *n* scores.

The main issue, of course, is you need to convert strings to integers for comparison.

```
from heapq import nlargest

leaderboard = nlargest(5, data, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

*Better still*, you can convert your input data to integers to begin with. You then no longer need to convert `str` to `int` as part of your sorting process. Something like:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

data = [(int(num), name) for num, nam in zip(numdata[0::2], numdata[1::2])]
leaderboard = nlargest(5, data, key=itemgetter(0))
```